# Jquery doesn't prevent the submit button action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

could you help me with these please:

I'm working on a PHP-Jquery-AJAX-JSON search, the idea is to have a php form where to type the ID of a specific employee and then via AJAX show the name in a div always in the same php form.

My problem is that I can show the message I would like to display in the div because when I press the submit button it always redirects to the action page specified in the form instead of just show the message into the div, so could you please tell me what is my problem? as you will see I specified e.preventDefault() in the code as show below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit_id").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $("input#ID_id");   

  if(validaForm(id)){ 

  $("#submit_id").hide();
  var url = $("#form_id").attr('action'); 
  var data = $("#form_id").serialize();   
  var type = $("#form_id").attr('method');

  $("#LoadingImage").show();
  $("#ajax_id").html("<div class='cargando'> realizando busqueda</div>");

$.ajax({
    url:url,          
    data:data,       
    type:type,      
    cache: false,  
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    encode: true

    .done(function(data) {   // using the done promise callback
       if ( ! data.success) {
        $("#LoadingImage").fadeOut();
          if (data.errors.ID_name) {
           $("#ajax_id").html("<div class='cargando'> Debe especificar el ID</div>");           
            } // if

        } // if 
        else {
            $("#ajax_id").html("<div class='cargando'> Tudo Ben</div>");
        } // else
    }) // done-promise


    .fail(function(data) {   // using the fail promise callback

        console.log(data);
    }); // fail-promise

    }); // AJAX call

  } // validaForm*/
            });
    });

    function validaForm(id){
        var id_val = id.val().trim();
        if((id_val=="") || id_val.replace(/s+/,'') == ''){
            alert("Favor ingrese el ID");
            id.addClass("posicionamiento");
            $("#div_id").html("<div class='error'>Debe especificar el nombre</div>");
            return false;
        }else{  
        id.removeClass("posicionamiento");
        $("#div_id").empty();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BUSCADOR</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="form_id" action="process.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Buscador Asincrono</legend>
        <p>ID a buscar: <input type="text" name="ID_name" id="ID_id"/>
          <div id="estado_id"></div></p>
        <p><input type="submit" id="submit_id" value="Buscar"/></p>
        <img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" align="center"/> <div id="ajax_id" align="center"></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to return FALSE in $("#submit_id").click function or use the "button" instead of "submit" component in your HTML form.

Comment: thanks, I just tried but still send me to the action specified php page

Comment: could you show us the HTML form?

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure the `done` and `fail` are in the wrong place? Why are they inside the object you pass to `$.ajax`?

Comment: Darian, this is the html code(I'm so sorry I don't know how to post it the right way)

<title>BUSCADOR</title>
</head>
<form method="post" id="form_id" action="process.php">
<fieldset>
<legend> Buscador Asincrono</legend>
 <p>ID a buscar: <input type="text" name="ID_name" id="ID_id"/><div id="estado_id"></div></p>
 <p><input type="submit" id="submit_id" value="Buscar"/></p>
 <img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" id="LoadingImage"  style="display:none" align="center"/>
 <div id="ajax_id" align="center"></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>

Comment: Crembo: I thought it was alright, is it wrong?

Comment: Did you try replace "<input type="submit"" by "<input type="button""

Comment: Please create a minimal demo; in the process you might solve your own problem. In the event that you still need help, the demo would be a good way for us to troubleshoot. .... May be there's an syntax error in your code that causes the rest of the code to be ignored.

Comment: Hello  Darian, I just tried the crembo suggestion and it already doesn't go to the specified php page in the form action, but now it doesn't show me any info, should I post a new question o just post the code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to prevent the click event instead of the submission itself.

Use `.submit` ([doc](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)) instead of `.click` in your event handler (and bind the event to the form instead of the submit button):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#form_id").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // ...
```

If you want to submit the form at a specific point, you can use then `$("#form_id").submit();`

**Update:** I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwah84w9/4/) to find out what was wrong:

You closed your `.ajax()` too late :-)

```
$.ajax({
// ... 
    .done(function(data) {   // using the done promise callback
    // ...
    }) // done-promise
    .fail(function(data) {   // using the fail promise callback
    // ...
    }); // fail-promise
}); // AJAX call
```

Change this to:

```
$.ajax({
   // ... 
}) // AJAX call
.done(function(data) {   // using the done promise callback
   // ...
}) // done-promise
.fail(function(data) {   // using the fail promise callback
    // ...
}); // fail-promise
```

It's corrected in the fiddle.

Comment: @PabloTobar what is the error you get with this solution?